# javascript confirmation dialog box

Tags: asp.net

I have a page with a button and when it is clicked, it will execute a long time task asynchronously. I tried to implement validation on that button using javascript and a confirmation dialog box will pop up when it is clicked. But when i clicked on 'Cancel' in the confirmation dialog box, the long time task still will be executed instead of returning false.

Any idea guys? Any help is appreciated!

**Code-Behind:**

```
btnPrint.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:submittingID='btnAdd';return validation();")

Public Sub LongTimeTask()
   .......
End Sub
```

**Javascript:**

```
function validation() {
    ....
    confirmPrint()
}

function confirmPrint() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to print? This process may take up to few minutes.") == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

Comment: this isn't enough information to help you. can you post some of the code you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`validation` doesn't return anything. try:

```
function validation() {
    //...
    return confirmPrint();
}
```

You can also remove the if from `confirmPrint`. Doesn't change the behavior, but no need to check for true and return true:

```
function confirmPrint() {
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to print?");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess from the description you gave is something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:if(confirm('Do you want to run this long task?')){ longTask() };">Link Text</a>
```

Comment: the long time task is not a javascript function, so it couldn't be executed from the client side...